# Want to read a tag data using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, html-table

The table I would like to read using Selenium is available at bottom of this page https://dps.psx.com.pk/

[HTML Source I would like read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqpSP.png)

I am perfectly reading all rows of the table except left most column. Here is my code

```
for row in tableFin.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
    print(row.find_elements_by_xpath("//td/a[@class='tbl__symbol']")) # This line of code is not working
    print([td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='right']")])
```

Could anyone please help in this regard

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Put a minimal version of your HTML code in the question, not as an image. Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) .

Comment: maybe read all `td` in row (not only `@class='right'`). If you need oly first column then get only first `td` in row using `element` without `s` at the end - `find_element_by_xpath` - or use `[0]` to get first element on list.

Comment: you forgot `.` at the beginning of xpath - maybe it makes problem.

Comment: do you get error message or wrong result? Describe in question what is wrong in your code. Put in question expected result and what you get. OR even better put code which we could run to see problem.

Comment: @furas Thanks ...your code suggests that it returns index-able list. Yes, I missed the dot I worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem to read first column if I only use `[1:]` to skip first row with headers.

I had to also add missing `.` in `xpath`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://dps.psx.com.pk/')

last_table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table")[-1]

for row in last_table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr")[1:]:
    print(row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td/a[@class='tbl__symbol']").text)
    print([td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='right']")])
```